# Open refine by google on private data

Tags: openrefine

Could OpenRefine be securely used for cleaning private data?

Tried on public data and ok but I'm not sure about data security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No data leaves your machine when using OpenRefine.  Although it's implemented as a web client/server app, the OpenRefine server runs on your personal machine and nothing is sent out over the Internet.  You can verify this by turning off your external network connections.

The one exception is if you use any external reconciliation services, in which case the data that you select as reconciliation criteria will be sent to whatever reconciliation service you are using.  All of the data cleaning and transformation operations can be done without any external network services.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by reconciliation services?

Comment: You don't need to worry about them if you don't know what they are.  They reconcile entities against databases such as Freebase, DBpedia, etc.  Other examples are here: https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Reconciliation-Service-API#examples